# Receive e-Mail when Stock Price reaches 52-week low?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a list of about **100 stocks. I would like to be emailed when any one of these stocks reaches a 52 week low**.  I can do basic programming in PHP etc., but is there a simpler way? **Does Yahoo Finance or Google Finance offer such a service**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't seem to be able to do this. From [Google Finance support](http://www.google.com/support/finance/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115771):

*Although we don't provide stock alerts at this time, you can request email updates or create an RSS feed about particular companies using Google Alerts. Google Alerts delivers relevant text and video results from blogs, discussion forums, news sites, and more. Visit http://www.google.com/alerts to get started.*

I can't seem to find anything like this on Yahoo Finance, either. I did find a website that seems to do this, [Zignals](http://www.zignals.com/main/stock_alerts/stock_alerts.aspx). I haven't used the service before, but it looks like it would be worth trying out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.  Zignals looks interesting.  Will post back with a mini review.

Comment: Yes, I think I like it.  There are a lot of features, but I am interested in getting email alerts based on 52 week lows.  Another interesting option for 'value investors' like myself is  get an alert based on when PE ratios hit some target.  At this point I like it and it seems to be the exact solution I asked for. The alerts have an intuitive interface too.